# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction') at ContractFactory.<anonymous>

Tags: hardhat

i am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction')
```

when i run the following command :

```
yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network Sepolia
```

deploy.js :

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
    const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
        "SimpleStorage"
    )
    console.log("Deploying the contract...")
    const SimpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
    await SimpleStorage.deployed()
    console.log(`Contract deployed at address: ${SimpleStorage.address}`)
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

hardhat.config.js :

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        Sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: PRIVATE_KEY,
            chainId: 11155111,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.18",
}
```

Comment: Try this in the config file `[PRIVATE_KEY]`

Comment: If i use [PRIVATE_KEY], then I get the following error ,                                              
                                                                                                                                   
`There's one or more errors in your config file    * Invalid account: #0 for network: Sepolia - Expected string, received undefined`

Comment: Are you taking the Private Key as a string, ie, in " "? It shouldn't be like that.

Comment: Thank you !!! Its working now

Answer (score 0):

You should put your accounts inside an array: `accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]` and make sure everything in your `.env` file is correct.
If u still getting error try to `console.log()` your env variables to see your dotenv package is working fine